# Filling the form I entered on my site on the other site

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress

I am trying to auto-fill the form I entered from the site with javascript subdomains, but there is no problem like this.

When I Enter Date My URL:

> [www.example.com/example](http://www.example.com/example)

But it works like this:

> https://sub.example.com/example?from_date=21%2F02%2F2021&to_date=26%2F02%2F2021&num_adults=1&num_children=1&check_availabilities=

So when I enter a date in the subdomain, there is no parameter in the URL address. Is there any way I can pass this without parameters?

My Script and Form

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var url = "http://example.com";
  var parameters = "foo=bar&bar=baz"; // Construct you form values like field=value&field2=value2&...

  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", parameters.length);
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
  xmlhttp.send(parameters);
}
```

```html
<div class="booknow-wrapper flexbox">
  <div class="title" style="font-size: 26px; font-weight:600;"><span></span> </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="booknow-card">
      <div class="booknow-input">
        <input type="date" name="from_date" id="arrival" value="from_picker" placeholder="Giriş Tarihi" required autocomplete="off">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="booknow-card">
      <div class="booknow-input">
        <input type="date" name="to_date" id="departure" value="to_picker" placeholder="Çıkış Tarihi" required autocomplete="off">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

And My Console Fetch

```
"referrer": "https://sub.exampla.com/booking",
"referrerPolicy": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin",
"body": - 
"from_date=15%2F02%2F2021&to_date=28%2F02%2F2021&num_adults=1&num_children=1&check_availabilities=",
  "method": "POST",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you are in the same domain and you want to propagate some data you filled in a page in your sub-domain, you can save the data in a browser storage, such as [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or [`sessionStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage):

```js
// register changes
window.localStorage.setItem(name, value);
window.sessionStorage.setItem(name, value);

// retrieving data
window.localStorage.getItem(name)
window.sessionStorage.getItem(name)
```

You can see following code in the snippet, but it will not work since it is sandboxed and `localStorage` is not allowed. You can run a test on the same code on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9xrkc2g6/). I write the snippet here just for reference.

```js
// select your elements
let btnInput = document.getElementById('storage_example_btn');
let btn = document.getElementById('save_btn');
let chgInput = document.getElementById('storage_example_change');
let shwRes = document.getElementById('show_results');
let results = document.getElementById('results');

// when click on "Save Data" button
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // save input data to storage
  sessionStorage.setItem('__SO_EXAMPLE_1__', btnInput.value);
});

// when the "onChange" input changes
chgInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    // save input data to storage
  sessionStorage.setItem('__SO_EXAMPLE_2__', chgInput.value);
});

// when click on "Show Storage" button
shwRes.addEventListener('click', () => {
    // get input data from storage
  let res1 = sessionStorage.getItem('__SO_EXAMPLE_1__')
  let res2 = sessionStorage.getItem('__SO_EXAMPLE_2__')
  // show it in the result div
  results.innerHTML = 'Session Storage<br/>Data from "Save Data" Input: ' +
                                            res1 + '<br/>Data from "onChange" Input: ' + res2
});
```

```html
Register data with a button:
<input id="storage_example_btn" type="date"/>
<button id="save_btn">Save Data</button><br/>

Register data <code>onChange</code>:
<input id="storage_example_change" type="date" />

<br/><br/>

<button id="show_results">Show Storage</button>
<div id="results"></div>
```

As `localStorage` implements the same interface of `sessionStorage` you can choose which one to use, depending on your application. Check from docs the differences.